Is there a way to make the rows of a gradio dataframe clickable?
I have the following script
import gradio as gr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def generate_random_dataframe():
    # Generate a random DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
    return df

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    generate_button = gr.Button("Generate Random DataFrame")
    
    # Create a DataFrame component to display the DataFrame
    output_df = gr.DataFrame()
    
    generate_button.click(fn=generate_random_dataframe, inputs=[], outputs=output_df)

demo.launch()

when run and the button click I got

My question is, is there a way to make this dataframe clickable?
For example I click on a row, and it calculates the sum of all numbers in the row and show it below in a text element

yep! You can add a click listener to the table and get the row value from the event
import gradio as gr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def generate_random_dataframe():
    # Generate a random DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
    return df


def df_select_callback(df: pd.DataFrame,  evt: gr.SelectData):
    return sum(evt.row_value)


with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    generate_button = gr.Button("Generate Random DataFrame")

    output_df = gr.DataFrame()
    sum_textarea = gr.Textbox("")
    generate_button.click(fn=generate_random_dataframe,
                          inputs=[], outputs=output_df)

    output_df.select(df_select_callback,
                     inputs=[output_df],
                     outputs=[sum_textarea])

demo.launch()

